# Javascript Reload after Jquery call with Php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem I've been trying to solve for the past days. I have a Jquery that updates an HTML and creates new content inside a div tag. The thing is that the javascript does not apply on the generated code. In other words, I could take the exact output that the Php gives me, put it in the html code directly and it works, but if it comes from the php while the page is running it won't work, it doesn't display the images correctly in a slideshow jflow.

Here is the HTML header

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.2.6.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.robwalsh.randomImageOnload.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/application.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.flow.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("div#controller").jFlow({
                slides: "#slides",
                width: "785px",
                height: "480px"
        });
    });


    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* SLIDESHOW AT HOMEPAGE */
    function slideSwitch() {
        var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

        if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

        var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
            : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

        $active.addClass('last-active');

        $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
            .addClass('active')
            .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
                $active.removeClass('active last-active');
            });
    }

    $(function() {
        setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    /* Function to show/hide the side menu for all images */
    function showDIV(e)
    {
        var notEmpty = true;
        var count = 0; 
        while(document.getElementById('subCat'+count) != null)
        {
            document.getElementById('subCat'+count).style.display = 'none'; 
            count++;
        }
        document.getElementById(e).style.display = 'block';
    }
    /* MENU INTERACTION */
    function showContent(cmd, id)
    {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("contentMain").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById("controller").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getMain.php?cmd="+cmd+"&id="+id,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-21909616-1']);
      _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.karimtabar.com']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();

    </script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO 8859-1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo/icon.jpg">
    <title>KARIM V TABAR PHOTOGRAPHY</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Karim V Tabar: photographer, new media, film, design." />
    </head>

    <body style="width:100%;">

    <div id="wholewrapper" >
    <!-- HEADER // TOP PORTION OF SITE -->
    <div id="logoheader">
    <h5 class="logo">
    <a href="#" title="Go Back">KARIM VICTOR TABAR</a>
    </h5>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="navcontainer">

    <?php
    $count = 0;
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator('images/menuImages') as $fileInfo) 
    {
        if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
        echo "<h2 class='acc_trigger' onclick=\"showDIV('subCat".$count."'); showContent(1, '".$fileInfo->getFilename() ."');\"><a href='#'>".$fileInfo->getFilename() ."</a></h2><div class='acc_container' id='container".$count."'><div class='block' name='subCats' id='subCat".$count."'><ul>";
        foreach (new DirectoryIterator('images/menuImages/'.$fileInfo) as $fileInfo2) 
        {
            if($fileInfo2->isDot() || $fileInfo2 == "thumbnails") continue;
            echo "<li><a href='#' onclick=\"showContent(2, '".$fileInfo->getFilename() ."/".$fileInfo2->getFilename()."');\">".$fileInfo2->getFilename() . "</a></li>";
        }
        echo "</ul></div></div>";$count++;
    }
    ?> 
        <div id="navigationlinks">
        <ul>
                <li><a href="pages/bio.html">BIO</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages/contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://blog.karimtabar.com/" target="_blank">BLOG</a></li></ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Images Thumbnails Categories -->
    <div id="contentMain">


    <div id="slideshow">
        <img src="images/homepage/bb1.jpg" width = "750px" alt="" class="active" />
        <img src="images/homepage/et1.jpg" width = "750px" alt="" />
        <img src="images/homepage/gaga1.jpg" width = "750px" alt="" />
        <img src="images/homepage/gaga2.jpg" width = "750px" alt="" />
        <img src="images/homepage/hkartwalk.jpg" width = "750px" alt="" />
        <img src="images/homepage/homepagegirl.jpg" width = "750px" alt="" />
        <img src="images/homepage/rodeo2.jpg" width = "750px" alt="" />
        <img src="images/homepage/rodeo5.jpg" width = "750px" alt="" />
        <img src="images/homepage/silverwig_gaga.jpg" width = "750px" alt="" />
        <img src="images/homepage/wavy1.jpg" width = "750px" alt="" />
        <img src="images/homepage/Wenya.jpg" width = "750px" alt="" />
    </div>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

And Here is the Php code that generates the new HTML(getMain.php)

```
    <?php

    $cmd=$_GET["cmd"];
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    /* The Thumbnail Display */
    if($cmd == 1)
    {
        echo "<div id='thumbnailcontentplaceholder'>";
        echo "<div id='thumbnailcontent'>";
        echo "<ul>";

        $dir = "images/menuImages/".$id."/thumbnails";
    // Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
        if (is_dir($dir)) {
            if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
                while (($file = readdir($dh)) != false) {
                    if(is_dir($file)) continue;
                 echo "<li>";
                 echo "<a href='#' title='".$file."'><img src='".$dir."/".$file."' alt='' /></a>";
                 echo "<div id='thumnailtitle'>".substr($file, 0, strpos($file, "."))."</div>";
                 echo "</li>";
              }
            closedir($dh);
            }
        }
        echo "</div></div>";
    }

    if($cmd == 2)
    { 
        $dir = "images/menuImages/".$id;
        $count = 1;
        $nFiles = countFiles($dir);

        echo "<div id='imageplaceholder'> \n";

        /* No1 No2 No3 ... */
        echo "<div id='controller' class='hidden'>\n";
        for($i =1; $i < $nFiles; $i++)
        {
            echo "<span class='jFlowControl'>No ".$i."</span>\n";
        }
        echo "</div>";

        echo "<div id='slides'>";
        if (is_dir($dir)) {
            if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
                while (($file = readdir($dh)) != false) {
                    if(is_dir($file)) continue;
                    echo "<div><img src='".$dir."/".$file."'></div>\n";
                 }
            closedir($dh);
            }
        }
        echo "</div>\n";
        echo '<div id="prevNext"> 
        <a id="prev_275997_0" class="jFlowPrev" href="#" onfocus="this.blur()">Previous</a>&nbsp;
        <span class="slide_slash">/</span>&nbsp;
        <a id="next_275997_0" class="jFlowNext" href="#" onfocus="this.blur()">Next image</a>&nbsp;</div>';

        echo '<div id="credits2">
        BEIJING BLUE<br>
        Photographed by: Karim V Tabar<br></div></div>';


    }

    function countFiles($dir)
    {
        $dh  = opendir($dir);
        while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
           $files[] = $filename;
        }

        if ($files) 
           $num_of_files = count($files) - 2; // we substract 2 because . and .. are included 
        else 
           die('there is an error'); 

        return $num_of_files;
    }

    ?>
```

Thanks

Real HTML that used to work was like this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/jquery-1.2.6.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../js/jquery.flow.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

    //Set default open/close settings
    $('.acc_container').hide(); //Hide/close all containers
    $('.acc_trigger:first').addClass('active').next().show(); //Add "active" class to first trigger, then show/open the immediate next container$(document).ready(function(){

    //On Click
    $('.acc_trigger').click(function(){
        ('#open').click()
    });

    });


    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("div#controller").jFlow({
                slides: "#slides",
                width: "785px",
                height: "480px"
        });
    });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-21909616-1']);
      _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.karimtabar.com']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();

    </script>





    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="../../css/stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../logo/icon.jpg">
    <title>KARIM V TABAR PHOTOGRAPHY</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Karim V Tabar: photographer, new media, film, design." />
    </head>
    <body style="width:100%;">

    <div id="wholewrapper">

    <!-- HEADER // TOP PORTION OF SITE -->
    <div id="logoheader">
    <h5 class="logo">
    <a href="../../index.html" title="Go Back">KARIM VICTOR TABAR</a>
    </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="navcontainer">

    <h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="../editorial.html">EDITORIAL</a></h2>

        <div class="acc_container">
            <div class="block"> <ul>                <li><a href="beijingblue.html">BEIJING BLUE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gaga.html">GAGA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="dtrouble.html">DOUBLE TROUBLE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="et.html">EXTRATERRESTRIAL DREAMS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="liferush.html">LIFE RUSH</a></li>
                    <li><a href="rodeoglam.html">RODEO GLAM</a></li>
                    <li><a href="wanderlust.html">WANDERLUST</a></li>
                    <li><a href="runawayangel.html">RUN AWAY ANGEL</a></li>
                    <li><a href="russianstandard.html">RUSSIAN STANDARD</a></li>
                    <li><a href="hollywoodhills.html">HOLLYWOOD HILLS</a></li></ul>

            </div>
        </div>  <h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="../travel.html">TRAVEL</a></h2>
        <div class="acc_container">
          <div class="block">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="../t/hk.html">HONG KONG</a></li> </li>
                    <li><a href="../t/dubai.html">DUBAI, UAE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../t/kyoto.html">KYOTO, JAPAN</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../t/miami.html">MIAMI, USA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../t/la.html">L.A., USA</a></li></ul>

            </div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="../art.html">ART</a></h2>
        <div class="acc_container">
                <div class="block">
                <ul>      <li><a href="../a/mirrorangel.html">MIRROR ANGEL</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../a/rouge.html">ROUGE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../a/violet.html">VIOLET</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../a/noire.html">NOIRE</a></li></ul>

            </div>
        </div>  <h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="../video.html">VIDEO</a></h2>
        <div class="acc_container">
            <div class="block">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="../v/zigmat.html">ZIGMAT - BETWEEN BULLETS VIDEO</a></li><li><a href="../v/zigmat-1.html">ZIGMAT - BEHIND THE SCNES</a></li></ul>
            </div>
        </div>    
        <h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="../exhibitions.html">EXHIBITIONS</a></h2>
        <div class="acc_container">
            <div class="block">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="../e/intemporelle.html">2009 RESIDENT, MONTRÉAL, CANADA</a></li><li><a href="../e/hkartwalk.html">2011 ART WALK, HONG KONG, CHINA</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!--     <h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="#">PRESS</a></h2>
        <div class="acc_container">
            <div class="block">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="press1.html">NME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="press2.html">LIVE FAST MAG</a></li>
                    <li><a href="press3.html">GURU</a></li></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    --><div id="navigationlinks">
        <ul>
                <li><a href="../bio.html">BIO</a></li>
                <li><a href="../contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://blog.karimtabar.com/" target="_blank">BLOG</a></li></ul>
        </div>  <!--   <div id="buyherelogo">
        <a href="../../store.html"><img src="../../store/buyhere.png" width="150" border="0"></a>
        </div>
    --></div>
    <!--IMAGE // RIGHT PORTION -->

    <div id="imageplaceholder"> 


    <div id="controller" class="hidden">
         <span class="jFlowControl">No 1</span>
         <span class="jFlowControl">No 2</span>
         <span class="jFlowControl">No 3</span>
         <span class="jFlowControl">No 4</span>
         <span class="jFlowControl">No 5</span>
         <span class="jFlowControl">No 6</span>
         <span class="jFlowControl">No 7</span>


    </div>

    <div id="slides">  
        <div><img src="../../images/fashion/beijingblue/bb1.jpg" width="785" height="480"></div>  
        <div><img src="../../images/fashion/beijingblue/bb2.jpg" width="785" height="480"></div>    
        <div><img src="../../images/fashion/beijingblue/bb3.jpg" width="785" height="480"></div> 
        <div><img src="../../images/fashion/beijingblue/bb4.jpg" width="785" height="480"></div>
        <div><img src="../../images/fashion/beijingblue/bb5.jpg" width="785" height="480"></div>    
        <div><img src="../../images/fashion/beijingblue/bb6.jpg" width="785" height="480"></div> 
        <div><img src="../../images/fashion/beijingblue/bb7.jpg" width="785" height="480"></div>        
    </div>  

    <div id="prevNext"> 
        <a id="prev_275997_0" class="jFlowPrev" href="#" onfocus="this.blur()">Previous</a>&nbsp;
        <span class="slide_slash">/</span>&nbsp;
        <a id="next_275997_0" class="jFlowNext" href="#" onfocus="this.blur()">Next image</a>&nbsp;

    </div>

    <div id="credits2">
        BEIJING BLUE<br>
        Photographed by: Karim V Tabar<br>


    </div>

    </div>



    </div>  


    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you bind events, or call jQuery functions, the element needs to exist in the DOM for jQuery to find it.

Because you are populating your page *after* the script has executed, there's no element's to be selected (despite placing the selection in a `document.ready` callback.

If you did a `console.log` on `$('div#controller')` you'd see an empty jQuery object.

If you, instead, used the complete callback to register your `jsFlow` call, you should see things working as expected.

Is there a reason you're not using jQuery's normalized [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/) functions?

Comment: The website was given to me in all html (around 40 pages), I needed to bring it down so that it regenerates. 
This is the website in all html http://www.karimtabar.com/ So what Im trying to do is the Image Viewer with the slide effect after you chose a category and view an album. What woudl you suggest me to do?

Comment: guyPW123, the <div id="contentMain"></div> needs to show first before all <script type="text/javascript"></javascript>. So move this container above your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You use `<div id="contentMain">` in the code, but you call it on `div#controller`? Anyways, it wouldn't work even if you specified the correct selector, because as zzzzBov answered, when the page loads, your div is empty. You have to recall the jFlow function after you update the content:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
    document.getElementById("contentMain").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

    $("div#contentMain").jFlow({
        slides: "#slides",
        width: "785px",
        height: "480px"
    });
}
```

Comment: The div controller is in the php. Thats how it was used before to control it. I tried what you just sent me Nemanja its not working

Comment: I change the content of the question, Ive put all the code there. Could help out more I think. I'm really stuck and this is pretty much the last thing I have to do to finish it