# Calling an html attr when html is echo'd

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am creating a list through echoing html from my controller to an ajax function. so my javascript get this data through ajax and create li's ...  then i want to call an attribute from this created html  ... its not working. ... what am I doing wrong?

JAVA SCRIPT

//To create list

```
$.ajax({
             url:'ol_locations',  // ol_locations is a controller, see below.
             dataType: 'html',

                success: function (data3){

            //  list elements in the ordered list


            $('ol.locations_list').html(data3);
                }});
//list populated successfully
```

Controller ol_location ............

public function ol_locations(){

```
    $this->load->model('model_location');
    $data = $this ->model_location -> fetch_location_data();
    $i=1;
    foreach ($data as $row){



        if ($row->Type == 'locality'){

            echo "<div data-color ='red' id='".$i."'><li><a href ='#'> <span class='location_title'>". $row -> Nickname . " </span> ". $row->FormattedAddress .
            "</a> <a class='remove_location' title='Remove this location' data-nid='{$row->Id}'
            style='float:right;'>x</a>" ." </li> </div>";
            $i++;
        }
        else {
                 echo "<div data-color ='red' id='".$i."'><li> <a href ='#'><span class='location_title'>". $row -> Nickname. " ". $row -> Radius ." km of </span> ". " </span> ". $row->FormattedAddress ."</a><a class='remove_location' title='Remove this location' data-nid='{$row->Id}'style='float:right;'>x</a>" ." </li> </div>";
            $i++;
        } }
}
```

---

now the HTML renders good ... but when i try to access any element in this "created html" nothing happens ...

for example alert ($('#1'). attr('color')); will give "null" or undefined.

I tried a lot of things like

var initial_location = $('ol.locations_list li a'). attr('href');

still null ...

I m really stuck here ...

Comment: I don't see an `$("ol.locations_list")` and it would be `$("#1").data('color')` or `$("#1").attr('data-color')`

Comment: Console your ajax data and in google chrome  browser  open console (ctrl+alt+j) then see what html your are being received...Heres the code for console....console.log($('ol.locations_list').html())

Comment: Similar problem and its solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958851/javascript-reload-after-jquery-call-with-php?rq=1

Comment: HTML is invalid... `LI` can't be a child of `DIV` and `DIV` can't be child of `OL`. Browser will often move invalid html when it can't parse it as written. Use w3c validator to check it

Comment: Is the html actually being added to the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say the html is added properly to your DOM, it might be the case that you're trying to access the new elements before they're actually loaded. Make sure to place any code related to the new elements only after `$('ol.locations_list').html(data3);`, for example -

```
$.ajax({
         url:'ol_locations',  // ol_locations is a controller, see below.
         dataType: 'html',

            success: function (data3){

        //  list elements in the ordered list


        $('ol.locations_list').html(data3);
}}).done(function() {
    alert ($("#1").attr('data-color'));
});
```

Comment: Javascript is in footer so, yes that might be the case ... When I view the page source I see nothing in html .. but can see everything through firebug and I can also see the generated html on the page.

Comment: Thanks Roy. You were right. The javascript was loading after the page without generated html was loaded ... the solution in my opinion to have part of the javascript load before the page and the other part after ... i just generated the code through php .. thanks everyone for their help

Comment: No problem. It's recommended to put all your code at one section, and if your code relates to DOM elements, put it after they are loaded using the above method or $(function() {}); - which means - after document finished loading. BTW if this answer solved your problem please consider upvoting and/or marking it as accepted answer.